# Flier colors in boxplot with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, statistics, boxplot

According to the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.boxplot.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.boxplot), the `Axes.boxplot` function takes a dictionary `flierprop` as argument to define the properties of the outliers. Unfortunately, I can't find the documentation concerning this dictionary. In particular, I would like to define the color of the border of the marker.

By default, empty circles are drawn. One can set the face color, [as shown in the example](https://matplotlib.org/examples/statistics/boxplot_demo.html). Nevertheless, the circle border is always a black line. I tried with the keys `color` and `markercolor` (the former has no effect, the latter produces an error).

**What should I do to set a color for the marker line?**

Comment: Do you try `edgecolor` property?

Comment: `markeredgecolor` did it! Thanks a lot. You can post this as an answer (or I can).

Comment: Yep, `edgecolor` is according to seaborn boxplot.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

To set marker color use property `markerfacecolor` but for border color - `markeredgecolor`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# fake up some data
spread = np.random.rand(50) * 100
center = np.ones(25) * 50
flier_high = np.random.rand(10) * 100 + 100
flier_low = np.random.rand(10) * -100
data = np.concatenate((spread, center, flier_high, flier_low), 0)

# plot. Set color of marker edge
flierprops = dict(marker='o', markerfacecolor='r', markersize=12,
                  linestyle='none', markeredgecolor='g')
plt.boxplot(data, flierprops=flierprops)

plt.show()
```

[image]

According to @Spiros the flierprops dictionary is documented here like other boxplot properties: http://matplotlib.org/users/dflt_style_changes.html?highlight=flierprops#boxplot

Comment: It could be worthwhile to add this information to the matplotlib documentation -- unless it is already there and I missed it.