# Black and white boxplots in Seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to draw multiple black-and-white boxplots using Python's Seaborn package. By default the plots are using a color palette. I would like to  draw them in solid black outline. The best I can come up with is:

```
# figure styles
sns.set_style('white')
sns.set_context('paper', font_scale=2)
plt.figure(figsize=(3, 5))
sns.set_style('ticks', {'axes.edgecolor': '0',  
                        'xtick.color': '0',
                        'ytick.color': '0'})

ax = sns.boxplot(x="test1", y="test2", data=dataset, color='white', width=.5)
sns.despine(offset=5, trim=True)
sns.plt.show()
```

Which produces something like:

[image]

I would like the box outlines to be black without any fill or changes in the color palette.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You have to set `edgecolor` of every boxes and the use `set_color` for six lines (whiskers and median)  associated with every box:

```
ax = sns.boxplot(x="day", y="total_bill", data=tips, color='white', width=.5, fliersize=0)

# iterate over boxes
for i,box in enumerate(ax.artists):
    box.set_edgecolor('black')
    box.set_facecolor('white')

    # iterate over whiskers and median lines
    for j in range(6*i,6*(i+1)):
         ax.lines[j].set_color('black')
```

If last cycle is applied for all artists and lines then it may be reduced to:

```
plt.setp(ax.artists, edgecolor = 'k', facecolor='w')
plt.setp(ax.lines, color='k')
```

where `ax` according to `boxplot`.

[image]

If you also need to set fliers' color follow this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43342864/2666859).

Comment: If you want to get really minimalist, you could do `showbox=False`.

Comment: you may need: `for i,box in enumerate(ax.patches):` due to this issue: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/20895

Answer (score 32):

I was just exploring this and it seems there is another way to do this now. Basically, there are the keywords `boxprops`, `medianprops`, `whiskerprops` and (you guessed it) `capprops`, all of which are dictionaries that may be passed to the boxplot func. I choose to define them above and then unpack them for readability:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

_to_plot = pd.DataFrame(
    {
     0: np.random.normal(0, 1, 100),
     1: np.random.normal(0, 2, 100),
     2: np.random.normal(-1, 1, 100),
     3: np.random.normal(-2, 2, 100)
     }
).melt()

PROPS = {
    'boxprops':{'facecolor':'none', 'edgecolor':'red'},
    'medianprops':{'color':'green'},
    'whiskerprops':{'color':'blue'},
    'capprops':{'color':'magenta'}
}

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10))
sns.boxplot(x='variable',y='value',
            data=_to_plot,
            showfliers=False,
            linewidth=1,
            ax=ax,
            **PROPS)
```

[image]